# What event works best for retrieving session storage values

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to use session storage to save the values of the slider on my browser. On page reload I keep getting my default 0.5 being displayed. The script seems fine, I am wondering if using a "change" event is not the best approach.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q8c4d32f/14/

```js
// With JQuery
$("#ex6").slider({
        tooltip: "hide"
});

$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
  let set = sessionStorage.setItem("slider", slideEvt.value);
});

$("#ex6").on("change", function(changeEvt) {
  let get = sessionStorage.getItem("slider");
});
```

```css
div{
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css"
      integrity="sha512-SZgE3m1he0aEF3tIxxnz/3mXu/u/wlMNxQSnE0Cni9j/O8Gs+TjM9tm1NX34nRQ7GiLwUEzwuE3Wv2FLz2667w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous" />


<!--Importing Javascript-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-f0VlzJbcEB6KiW8ZVtL+5HWPDyW1+nJEjguZ5IVnSQkvZbwBt2RfCBY0CBO1PsMAqxxrG4Di6TfsCPP3ZRwKpA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div>
<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="0.0" data-slider-max="1.0" data-slider-step=".1" data-slider-value="0.5"/>
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">0.5</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Also your usage of `let set` and `let get`, within the context of the code you have provided us, are pointless.

Comment: Actually your fiddle works.  So what is the problem again?

Comment: On page reload my previous selected value won't get displayed. It defaults to 0.5. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Right, it defaults to 0.5 because that's what you have it set as.  You are not doing anything with the session storage on page load.  You are creating event handlers.  The event handlers will not execute until their event happens.  If you want to reload the value on page load, you have to do that outside of an event handler, or do it in a document ready or page load event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the slider inside a document ready after having retreived the session storage.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let get = sessionStorage.getItem("slider") || 0.5 // If there is no session storage, use 0.5
  console.log(get);
  
  $("#ex6").slider({
        tooltip: "hide",
        value: get
  });

  $("#ex6SliderVal").text(get);
})
```

Your [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/4zjakr5e/10/)

Comment: Interesting the way you used the key value in the slider function. This approach makes sense, and is effective. Thanks!

Comment: Yes... ;) that in fact, is an option object you can pass on initialisation. see [bootstrap slider options](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#options)